# Cannot load source for localhost php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm writing the code for a form, and submitting it to a php file using $.get().

On submitting the form, Firebug responds with the error : `Failed to load source for: http://localhost/llm/llm.php?name=afaf`

If I only write `http://localhost/llm/llm.php?name=afaf` in the address bar then it works properly!

Here's my html and php code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Backoffice</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function create(){
  var fname = document.joinee.name.value;
  alert(fname);
  $.get("llm.php", {name:fname}, function(res) {
   alert(res);
   console.log(res);
         });
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="joinee">
    Name: <input type="text" size="30" id="name"/><br />
 Parent: <input type="text" size="30" id="parent"/><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="create()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['name'];

?>
```

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of firebug error?

Comment: Btw, since you're using jQuery, why it is `document.joinee.name.value`, and not `$('#name').val()`?

Comment: @zerkms: Well here's the screenshot http://img258.imageshack.us/img258/3279/firebug.jpg And I made the change to $('#name').val()..

Comment: @Hrishikesh Choudhari: that is what your script has returned. Since it is `200` - the request finished successfully.

Comment: @zerkms: If the request is finished successfully then why isnt the echo being printed in ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025445/javascript-failed-to-load-source-for-http-localhost-js-m-js perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've have that if I just remove the `<form>` tags, then it all works fine!! I tried that on both of my different laptops, one had WAMP and the other had the most recent version of XAMPP.

Any reason why ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your request to...

```
   $.ajax({
      url: 'llm.php',
      data: {name:fname},
      success: function (r) {
    console.log(r);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
    console.log(status);
    console.log(error);
    }
    });
    }


If you're using [Firebug][1] then you should be able to view the response of the ajax request without console.log.
```

Comment: What can replacing `$.get` with `$.ajax` change?

Comment: @Webnet: I made the changes as above.. The console doesnt show any error at all except in the Net Panel where I still get the "failed to load source.." error. Here's a shot of my firebug: http://img258.imageshack.us/img258/3279/firebug.jpg

Comment: Is the console logging anything at all?  If not, go to the Console tab, click the down arrow and select "Enable" @zerkms - I didn't say it would

Comment: @Webnet: the console log's screenshot is here.. http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/9210/firebug1.jpg. I've enabled the default "Show Javascript errors and Show XMLHttpRequest errors"..

Comment: That screenshot still shows a progress bar next to the ajax request.  You can't see the response till after it's finished executing

Comment: @Webnet: the request never finishes.. But I think I've found the solution.. Look below.