# Getting error in console : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, oracle11g

I have refresh my application page and getting this error in console 
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

I have tried to re-install the XAMPP version but this doesnt work for me.

Comment: I have the same problem, what solution did solve your problem?

Comment: I had the same problem and used Laragon. In Laragon settings, I just changed the port from 80 to 8080 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you are using chrome.
 The problem is  the certificate mismatch or the expiration of the certificate.Check your certificate properly.

Just visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083453/console-errors-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response) for more information.

Comment: @ code Lover : but i am getting this error on Mozilla also. What you think its just a browser isuue?

Comment: @lakhan its because of the certificate mismatch as i said

Comment: i checked my certificate expiration is in 2015. as you said its about mismatch.how to check whether is mismatched or not...because my other sites are working fine...only the application i am running is not.

Comment: @lakhan see after searching about this i came into a conclusion that this can be cause dut to many reason ..it can be also due to the driver you are using ..maybe it will be fine if you update your network drivers to latest version..see here http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1982982/err-connection-reset-error-chrome.html

Comment: Yes but this is only comming when i am running my application on my localhost... any idea in case of localhost comes in part.

Comment: @lakhan have you checked your attrbute tag??..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025445/javascript-failed-to-load-source-for-http-localhost-js-m-js

Comment: Yes this is not the issue...:(

Comment: @lakhan as i told you there are many problem which can cause this ..maybe a  research can help you ..:) ..i have provided only some of the issue which can cause this but there are many issues ..

Answer (score 20):

I'm using chrome too and facing same problem on my localhost.
I did a lot of things like clear using CCleaner and restart OS. But my problem was solved with clearing cookie.
In order to clear cookie:

1. Go to Chrome settings > Privacy > Content Settings > Cookie > All cookie and Site Data > Delete domain problem

**OR**

2. Right Click > Inspect Element > Tab Resources > Cookie (Left Menu) > Select domain > Delete All cookie One By One (Right Menu)

Comment: This is is actually the real answer, I have found some faulty database index of a site in cookies and this error disapered after I have deleted taht data base, thank you.

Comment: I have deleted the related domain's cookie but it did not help. I was working on localhost so I deleted the all cookie related with the localhost. Any idea? @user164863

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue using Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.

My client sent a lot of requests when refreshing (hard reloading) my application page in the browser and every time some of the last requests resulted in this error in console:

> GET `http://example.com/api/v1/my/resource` net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

It turned out that my client was reaching the maximum amount of threads that was allowed. The threads exceeding this configured ceiling are simply not handled by Apache at all resulting in the connection reset error response.

The amount of threads can be easily raised by setting the `ThreadsPerChild` value for the module in question. 
The easiest way to make such change is to uncomment the Server-pool management config file `conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf` and then editing the preset values in the file to desired values.

**1) Uncomment the Server-pool management file**

```
# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
```

**2) Open and edit the file `conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf` and raise the amount of threads**

In my case I had to change the threads for the `mpm_winnt_module`:

```
# raised the amount of threads for mpm_winnt_module to 250
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild        250
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

A comprehensive explanation on these Server-pool management configuration settings can be found in [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16376839/1697459).

Answer (score 5):

Try it with the browser in incognito mode first.  If incognito works it's probably an extension or settings issue with the browser(s) and not a server issue.  Hopefully this saves someone the headache I just went through.

Comment: This helped me figure out my issue too, was also my VPN like @user7630000 said. Just removed it from my Chrome browser and bam issue fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error with Symfony on wamp and PHP 7.0.0.

#### symptoms

None of the JS and CSS dependencies was loaded on the "dev" environnement, with error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

#### solution

It's effectively a certificate problem in `php.ini`.
You need to set the property `curl.cainfo` to a valid certificate in the line :

```
curl.cainfo = C:\your\wamp\path\bin\cacert\cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

Turning off my VPN resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error was happening on localhost, but it disappeared when routing it through ngrok and was replaced with a MUCH more helpful error (net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING) that led me here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29969400

Basically, the Kestrel server I was using was saying it was chunked output, but not terminating it properly.  I double checked it with Fiddler which confirmed the error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have used .woff files from git repository, and i noticed git has changed my binary files. That with some null character at the file endings.
I have rechanged to the orgnal .woff source files and it has corrected!

Also i have understood visual studio controller sending corrupted error like ERR_CONNECTION_RESET from the controller when it gots null character

I shared for all who live this problem

Answer (score 0):

(Short) In my case :
My URL redirected to https://localhost instead of http://localhost
Just try to click the first link and you will know about HOW?

(LONG)
As extra, I add summary about this situation Based on Timing breakdown phases from [developer.chrome.com](https:///docs/devtools/network/reference/#timing-explanation) eg:

- Queueing
- Stalled
- DNS Lookup
- Initial connection (TCP,SSL)
- Request sent
- ServiceWorker Preparation
- Request to ServiceWorker
- Waiting (TTFB)
- Content Download
- Receiving Push
- Reading Push

How:

1. Right click on page
2. Click Inspect
3. Clik Network
4. Clik on your Trouble URL
5. Clik Timing tab

[image: Timing Tab]

Click on *Explanation*, and there a solution based on your case.

In my case **Stalled**: and explained in that document:

Here its 2 phase for my case:

**Queueing**. The browser queues requests when:

- There are higher priority requests.
- There are already six TCP connections open for this origin, which is
  the limit. Applies to HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 only.
- The browser is briefly allocating space in the disk cache

**Stalled**. The request could be stalled for any of the reasons described in Queueing.

Just read, information on that Timing Tab and I hope this can help anyone who experinced similar problem

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen when the HTTP response contains a **header which exceeds 16KB**, which is the maximum the browser can handle (Chrome, Edge, Firefox).

It can be tested with Postman, where the request will complete without any error, but it will fail in the browser.