# Laravel - unable to run app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I clone one big private project in my new company. I update all denpendecies with composer, set up database, run migrations and seeding.
When I access app I get strange error:[image: laravel error]

But localhost is working fine, I can browse all files normaly, and run other laravel apps normaly, I can access root folder of this project everthing works fine, but when I access public folder I get this error. I tried with virtual host but error still appers. This error is very strange for me because apache or php(laravel) are not showing any error.

Comment: I think it is not working because something is wrong. I could attach a photo of myself saying it, but I'm lazy.

Comment: Showing a non english error page is not really helpful in here. From what I can translate this means that the page is not available. You would need to provide some more info (OS, setup, homestead(??), DNS etc.) so that we can help you more.From the top of my head I would tell you to ping the (fake?) domain and see if this is available.

Comment: Have you correctly set the `'url'` key in `config/app.php` ? Also [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931566/getting-error-in-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-reset) that might be related.

Comment: You might have forgot to set the permissions for `storage` directory and `bootstrap/cache` directory. They should be writable by your web server. More info on [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#configuration)

Comment: os is windows so permissions are not problem, I don't use vagrant/homestead, DNS is not problem because other localhost file listing and laravel aps work fine.

Comment: alariva -> problem is not the same as this one you point in your comment.

Comment: tix3 -> I think that I described problem fine. ERR_CONNECTION_RESET is relevant error, other non english text is not relevant.

Comment: are you sure you're clean from laravel-compiled files? try `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan route:clear`. also, try to post log (`storage\logs\laravel.log`) instead of this non-self-explaining screenshoot. also updating dependencies for a stable system is rather unsafe, better runs the vanilla first - it might break compatibility among packages.

Comment: it works fine on homestead, but on localhost is the same error.