# phpmyadmin net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on AJAX actions

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin works fine. It doesn't work when I try to perform a lot of AJAX operations such as clicking "edit" on a record. Even if I try to run a SQL->SELECT->Go I have problems.

I'm getting this error from my chrome dev console:

**net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

[image: phpmyadmin AJAX error]

I tried with different db/users/full privileges and with different browsers.
I did not found a single post about this on Google.

I have full access to the server, which is a **Debian** server (Apache/2.4.10  libmysql - 5.5.47). PHP memory limit is very high.

**No errors at all on APACHE error.log**.

What can I do to identify the problem?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931566/getting-error-in-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-reset/30222307#30222307) question?

Comment: @Hatef yes I have, I tried with different browser, even without existing cookies. My problem is that I cannot identify the cause of this bug.