# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, handlebars.js

Am using handlebars and doing a basic form GET to **createnewpassword.hbs** as below but am getting **net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** error in browser and fails to load the page. Am really stuck with this. Please suggest some pointers or any help will be appreciated.

> form1.hbs

```
  <form name="form1" id="form1" action="/forgotpassword/createnewPassword" method="GET" >
    <input type="hidden" name="tk" id="tk" value="123456">
    <input type="submit" name="submitVals" / >
  </form>
```

And am listening the route on the nodejs like

> app.js

```
app.get('/forgotpassword/createnewpassword', function(req,res){
    var context = {
      appTitle : "create new password"
     }
    res.render('/filepath/createnewpassword' , context);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a cookie problem and most often seen with chrome users

Go to Chrome settings > Privacy > Content Settings > Cookie > All cookie and Site Data > Delete domain problem

OR

Right Click > Inspect Element > Tab Resources > Cookie (Left Menu) > Select domain > Delete All cookie One By One (Right Menu)

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931566/getting-error-in-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-reset)