# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on Php web application

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a website hosted in bigrock vps CENTOS server.

> My problem is , whenever i try to load my website, it gets easily
>   loaded on first attempt. But after sometime it is not responding and
>   in console it shows error like **Failed to load resource:
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**. and at that time cpanel is also not
>   accessible.

All the assets excluding some fonts are loaded from bigrock server. Codeigniter is the framework am using.

http://test.hyperkhaleej.com i hosted my website here please take a look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error in console : Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_CONNECTION\_RESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931566/getting-error-in-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-reset)

Comment: @Adam A     When am loading using https://  everything is fine so far.

Comment: Do you have an SSL cert installed on the server?

Comment: @Adam A  - Yes i have and it is going to expire soon.Now it is working fine.