# Why does happen Wordpress HTTP ERROR when uploading large files in IIS7 Server?

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, iis, file-upload

I have a **Windows 2012 R2** Server running **PHP 7.1** Hosting a **Wordpress** on **IIS7**

The default upload size for WordPress media library was **2MB**, I was able to change this via `php.ini` to **512MB**. But when uploading large files, especially over about 70MB the upload starts and then pauses and hangs in the middle. After the server times-out, I then get the WordPress HTTP error.
`net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` on the inspect console.

This timeout Happens within the range of 10 - 20 seconds of the upload's start, and in a different production environment, this happens instantly.

[image: Wordpress Error]
[image: Console Error]

I have done a lot of searching and created a new environment with a new WordPress on a windows setup but ran into the same issue on a Windows 2007 SP2 Setup.

`Inside wp-config.php`

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '512M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '512M' );
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '1024M' );
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

`inside web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1048576" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1048576"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <rewrite>
      <rules/>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

`inside php.ini`

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
memory_limit = 1024M
max_execution_time = 300
```

on the IIS control panel
[image: Site Application Advanced Settings]

Not sure what else can be done to fix this. The error shows up on a basic WordPress install with the basic theme.

Comment: Have you tried to clear your cache? [See this answer for more information:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931566/getting-error-in-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-reset)

Comment: @AbdushSamadMiah cache? why would cache cause this? I have restarted the machine a few times.

Comment: Could you please give back the error code (404 ?) with its iis substatus ?

Comment: Try setting the `post_max_size` bigger than the upload if you or a user does upload a 512MB file there is no room for any other form information so i normally set the is 2 or 5 mb higher than the max post-size limit but this wont fix your problem just a bit of advice. what will is that IIS has it's own file size limit before PHP kicks in checkout http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm

Comment: @MartinBarker The problem is it errors much sooner than it even reach any cap.

Comment: @Oulalahakabu The server Timeouts with no response back.

Comment: @vico you would be surprised the upload limit is is only 28.61 MB by default so you could be hitting that upload limit rather fast. hell, my home broadband connection would hit that limit it about 4 seconds. and standard home broadband would hit that limit in about 18 seconds at 2Mb

Comment: @MartinBarker Like i stated above, I have done a local upload of 500 mb no problem, so it shouldn't be a size limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that the IIS Web Server has it's own Upload/content size limit before PHP is enabled for the connection so setting the PHP stuff controls it for PHP but not for IIS.

you can read about it and how to fix at http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm

The Jist of it is add

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="536870912" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

To a web.config in the public or root directory of your site. Where the `maxAllowedContentLength` attribute is the number of bytes of your 'post_max_size' in the case of 512MB `(512*1024*1024) = 536870912`

Comment: Have you restarted IIS since including all these changes and i don't mean the site i mean the global IIS service?

Comment: Yes I have restarted the machine even.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but something like this happened to us (windows w/ IIS running PHP).  Took forever to figure out and I couldn't believe it when I found it.

With that said, try clearing your Windows temp Directory (C:\Windows\Temp).  PHP stores session files there that often don't get deleted.  If they grow to be too many it can cause the issue you are describing. No guarantees, of course, but worth a shot.