# Windows server 2019 and IIS 10 GET,POST work fine but can't use PUT,DELETE from external

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, iis

I try to install react(axios) in IIS and use node.js as server GET,POST work fine but PUT,DELETE (can use in internal) did not
I tested in Linux server node.js work fine, I try to solve for week such as ExtensionlessUrlHandler ,cors, etc. now I disable Request filter in IIS still did not work.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

(I can not upload picture.)

- Common HTTP Features (4 of 6 installed)

  - Default Document
  - Directory Browsing
  - HTTP Errors
  - Static Content
- Health and Diagnostics

  - HTTP Logging
- Performance

  - Static Content Compression
- Application Development

  - CGI
  - ISAPI Extensions
  - ISAPI Filters
  - WebSocket Protocol
- Management Tools

  - IIS Management Console

web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by cookies and most often seen with chrome users.
You can try the following steps to solve your problem.

Go to Chrome settings > Privacy and security > Cookies and other site data > Cookie > All cookie and Site Data > Delete domain problem

Or you can refer to this link: [Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931566/getting-error-in-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-reset)

Comment: I use Microsoft edge. And I was doing this still not work.

Comment: Turn off your firewall, and then try it again.

Comment: It may also be certificate mismatch or the expiration of the certificate. Check your certificate properly.

Comment: Here is the solution to the [ERR_CONNECTION_RESET](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-connection-reset/#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20most%20common,have%20added%20to%20your%20browser.) error for your reference.