# jQuery and Bootstrap not working: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4

My jQuery and Bootstrap is not loading and returns me the following error message:

GET https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

GET https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Imports:

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Bootstrap:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931566/getting-error-in-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-reset ?

Answer (score -1):

try use this in all lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js">
```

Comment: it's not `stylesheet` it is `JavaScript`

Comment: @KamleshPaul using rel="JavaScript" should it work? Anyways it just gives me the error sometimes..